# CSS design and images

Tags: css, image, background

I have this link below:

http://www.noupe.com/

The style is used alot if you look at the flowers in the upper left. Is this done using
something like

```
<div> upper flower part image </div>
<div> lower flower part image</div>
```

Or using z-index?

Specifically around where the code reads `<div id="header" > </div>` This shows the bottom part
of the flower and somewhere above shows the upper part of the flower

Is the image sliced to create that effect?

Any simple example to highlight this effect?

Comment: Probably it was sliced, than positioned with position:absolute and then z-index was used to force the image to front..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the image is sliced into multiple parts and then set as a background image on containers...

You can see one of the slices here...

http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/themes/noupe/images/decor-1.png

Here is the CSS which was used to make that happen...

```
#main .decor-1 {
background: url(http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/themes/noupe/images/decor-1.png) no-repeat;
width: 584px;
height: 211px;
position: absolute;
left: -97px;
top: -123px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source. They use non-semantic classes such as `decor-1` with background images that are absolutely positioned over the rest of the site.

```
#main .decor-1 {
background: url(image) no-repeat;
width: 584px;
height: 211px;
position: absolute;
left: -97px;
top: -123px;
}
```

Comment: This was just beaten out but correct as well.